# Dynamic title with angular1.5 components meteor and ui-router

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, components, angular-meteor

- **angular 1.5**

  - **meteor**
  - **angular-ui-router**

As you know in the tutorial parties from **angular-meteor** webpage, there exist a component called `<navigation></navigation>` and `<ui-view></ui-view>`

my question is:

how would be come to a dynamic title? I mean, that instead "Home title" will be a "Details title", or others titles depend to the .state . 
It's possible to pass name variable to navigation component?

I think that with `bindings` in `.components.config` but I dont know how.

iIn the img attached I put as parent component access and their childrens are login, registrer, and forgot. The title of the each .states would be in the title component

[image]

```
<title title="title"></title>
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

In the js:

```
function config($stateProvider) {
    'ngInject';

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            template: '<login></login>'
            I think that here is the bindings jajaja
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add listener on `$stateChangeSuccess` event, and set document title in event handler. `$stateChangeSuccess` event would be fired once the state transition is complete:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState){

     switch(toState.name){
         case 'detail': document.title = 'Detail Page';break;
         case 'main': document.title = 'Main Page';break;
         case 'profile': document.title = 'Profile Page';break;
     } 

 })
```

Comment: @MarkCen thanks for your time, I realy apreciate. well ,I will try to implement it. I working in my a pluker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/lnHqEKOwoSVPZ8am69T9?p=preview)

Comment: what about fetching data and populating the meta tags on callback?